# Folder permission configuration for online uploads and forbidden direct access - 403 error

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions, http-status-code-403

We are trying to create a form for our users where they can upload images to our site.
Lets say that we are uploading all the images to the folder images/uploads.

If the permissions for this folder are set to

> 777,

it works perfectly well as all the permissions are granted. But if someone types on the browser: mydomain.com/images/uploads, any intruder can have access to all the files uploaded.

If we change the permissions to

> 711

now it is forbidden (403 error) for intruders to access directly to mydomain.com/images/uploads but our users can no longer upload files as we get a php error "Permissions denied"

What is the best configuration for this case?

Comment: Going by [this](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html) I would guess 722, but I'm no linux expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.htaccess` to prevent access directory listing

```
 Options -Indexes
```

You can also use this to prevent image hot linking

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.mydomain.com/angryman.gif [R,L]
```

Comment: Of course, you are right. Alternatively place an empty index.html file in the directory.

Comment: `index.html` would only work on current direct but not in sub directly .. that mean you have to copy it in every folder .. don't think that is effective @vascowhite

Comment: Thanks +1 to you too for contribution

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, actually that is the solution we came up with so far, in PHP we create an index file that redirects the user to the root, but we don't like this solution, as @Baba says it is not very effective and fills up the folders with index files. I think Baba has a very good solution. Baba: How can I do this only for all the folder inside the images/uploads folder, but not to apply it to the files? Thanks.

Comment: just put the `.htacces` file in the `images/uploads` folder only